# Possible directions in noncommutative geometry

Tags: noncommutative-geometry, fa.functional-analysis

I recently came across noncommutative geometry and found it rather interesting. I should mention that I'm a graduate student considering options for my research and if I were to name an area which I'm interested in, then it would be functional analysis including operator algebras etc., and that was how I got to know about noncommutative geometry. From what I've been told, noncommutative geometry is a very broad area so I would think that one can go in many different directions after entering the field. What I would like to find out is what some of these directions are. Also, if I am to go into this field, my motivation will probably be functional analytic so I will be particularly interested to know if there is an approach that suits me.

Comment: Please read: http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

To be more positive: don't you have in your department a professor / post-doc / more advanced PhD student with whom you could discuss this (rather vague) question over coffee?

Comment: i think so but I being a newbie myself I couldn't resist to pour my knowledge over


Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You look into the book "Noncommutative Dynamics and E0 semigroups" by William Arveson
2) There is an approach to attack multivariate operator theory through algebraic geometry.You may look to "Operator Theory and Complex Geometry"  by douglas for an introduction
3)You may look into brown,douglas,fillimore's paper in essential normality and K-Homology which was a precursor to connes approach
4)or look into connes's book

Comment: it's my personal opinion but I think the second approach may go a long 
way in the future.the heart of the approach is "arveson conjecture" which relates homogeneous varieties in the unit ball of $C^n $ with essential normality of d-shift operators vaguely



Answer (score 2):

Connes' book is pretty tough to get through as a beginner.  I would suggest as an alternative the book *Elements of Noncommutative Geometry* by Gracia-Bondia, Varilly, and Figueroa.  Or for a more concise, but less thorough, introduction, I like Varilly's book *An Introduction to Noncommutative Geometry*, which is also a little more recent.

Comment: In view of your comment on OP: did you flag for moderators attention to make it CW. If not the procedure seems somewhat unfortunate since if OP turns the question into CW, your answer would stay *non-CW* (except moderators still notice it or you change it manually, of course). 

Comment: @quid: Yes, he did.

Comment: @S. Carnahan: Thanks for letting me know.  